# Get combined results from different measurements

Tags: influxdb

I have two different measurements with different fields but with same tags.

Example:

```
Name: measurement1
Tags: prd
-------------------
time    prd   id    value
x.x.x   AV    1234  12345
y.y.y   SK    567   5678

Name: measurement2
Tags: prd
-------------------
time    prd  name   dept
a.a.a   SK   Rob    000
b.b.b   AV   Jack   111
```

From the above example,

```
Select * from measurement1, measurement2 where prd='AV'
```

This query doesn't combine all field values as result.

Can I get the below result ? Is it possible to combine field values from two different measurements based on a tag value ?

```
time    prd    id    value   name   dept  
x.x.x   AV     1234  12345   -      -  
b.b.b   AV     -     -       Jack   111
```

PS: I'm new to InfluxDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. Individual measurements will be grouped by the measurement name.

It is not possible to combine fields from multiple measurements, nor perform functions across measurements.

In output data, each measurement's fields and values are returned per measurement, eg:

```
name: measurement1
<fields>
---------
<data>

name: measurement2
<fields>
---------
<data>
```